# Why any theory of spacetime atoms would be wrong from start? What about causal sets?

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete

After watching this public talk by Nina Arkani-Hamed titled "The doom of spacetime", I can't fully understand what he said in the answer to an audience question about gravity. He said we can't simply propose the existence of spacetime atoms, because that would contradict General Relativity right from the start. He explained that simply adding some crystalline structure on lower scale is impossible because vacuum has no scale. I am probably misquoting him, but he definitely ruled out any future theory where spacetime would emerge from any such structure in fashion similar to a table surface emerging from molecules of wood, because the table is anchored, but basic symmetries of GR do not allow anything like that in a vacuum. Can someone explain to me what symmetries would be violated and how? Where does it place a causal set hypothesis?
https://youtu.be/qTx98PUW6lE

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but presumably he's talking about the fact that spacetime is a Lorentzian manifold, which means it is invariant under infinitesimal transformations. If spacetime is made of atoms, the notion of infinitesimal transformations breaks down since you must consider atomic transformations. Causal sets says that GR is the limit of an atomic spacetime theory.

Comment: I agree with @BobakHashemi. Quantized manifolds emerge naturally from Connes' noncommutative geometry and the continuum limit gives ordinary Riemann's geometry. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2471 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0977.

Comment: Does this mean causal set theory is wrong?

Comment: @BobakHashemi perhaps I did not make it clear, but Nima was only considering possibilities that were compatible with GR and all the current data and observations. According to him space atoms must be ruled out on that basis. My question is: does causal set hypothesis fall under this category?